# How to execute a Function within a When-statement?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-when

I am using the following `when`-statement in Kotlin:

```
when(name) {
    "Sun" -> print("Sun is a Star")
    "Moon" -> print("Moon is a Satellite")
    "Earth" -> print("Earth is a planet")
}
```

And I have a function `foo()`.

This function should be executed for every case of the `when`-statement.

I tried:

```
when(name) {
    "Sun" -> print("Sun is a Star")
    "Moon" -> print("Moon is a Satellite")
    "Earth" -> print("Earth is a planet")
    foo()
}
```

But I get an error.

How do I make a `foo()` function call within the `when`-statement?

Comment: what do you mean by "within the when statement"? In which of the cases?

Comment: You need `foo()` to be fired, regardless what the `name` value is? Then place the call `foo()` after `when() {}`

Comment: @f1sh in all cases

Comment: @Michael then why does it need to be inside the `when`?

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to fire `foo()` from `when`, you can define a function, let's call it `fooPrint()` that prints the provided message and then invokes `foo()`:

```
fun fooPrint(message: String) {
    print(message)
    foo()
}
```

And use this function with `when`:

```
when(name) {
    "Sun" -> fooPrint("Sun is a Star")
    "Moon" -> fooPrint("Moon is a Satellite")
    "Earth" -> fooPrint("Earth is a planet")
}
```

Alternatively, as I've said in the comment, you can simply invoke `foo()` outside your `when` expression:

```
when(name) {
    "Sun" -> print("Sun is a Star")
    "Moon" -> print("Moon is a Satellite")
    "Earth" -> print("Earth is a planet")
}
foo()
```

Answer (score 1):

Question is if list of name is exhaustive. If it is, you can do like Alexander Ivanchenko suggests:

```
when(name) {
    "Sun" -> print("Sun is a Star")
    /** other code goes here */
}
foo()
```

Else:

```
when(name) {
    "Sun" -> {
        print("Sun is a Star")
        foo()
    }
    /** other code goes here */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for post, I need foo() method will be executed always